# What are the asymptotics in $k$ of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+k)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, operator-theory, asymptotics

Define the sum $$S_k = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+k)}$$ for all integers $k\ge0$. We know that $S_0=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $S_1=1$. Is it possible to write out $S_k$ explicitly for larger values of $k$, or at the very least give some asymptotic expression for $k$? All I actually need to know is whether $S=(S_k)_{k=0}^\infty\in\ell^2$, but I'd be interested in the answers to the previous questions as well.

(My motivation for this is to show that the operator that satisfies $\langle A e_i,e_j\rangle_{\ell^2(\mathbb N)} = \frac{1}{i+j-1}$ is not bounded on $\ell^2$, showing that Schur's condition does not hold if we replace $\ell^1$-boundedness with $\ell^2$-boundedness)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $0\not=k\in\mathbb{N}$ the series telescopes:

$$S_k={1\over k}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left({1\over n}-{1\over n+k}\right)={1\over k}\left(1+{1\over2}+\cdots+{1\over k}\right)\approx{\log k\over k}$$

so the sum $\sum S_k^2$ converges.

Comment: I think the middle result (which is exact for integer $k$) is more along the lines of what the OP wanted.

Comment: No, this is what I wanted, I was expecting the answer to be a lot trickier than it actually is.

Comment: The reason I was asking this was in order to find an infinite matrix with rows and columns uniformly bounded in $\ell^2$ which is nonetheless not a bounded operator on $\ell^2$. Are you aware of any such matrix?

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine, you would do well to ask that as its own, stand-alone question.